# Sortablejs auto-scroll speed according to distance from edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, sortablejs, react-beautiful-dnd

The auto-scroll of sortablejs feels like it barely works. Sometimes it lags. I'm working on an app that needs a smooth scroll similar to how it works in react-beautiful-dnd. It starts scrolling slowly when you go close to the edge and it speeds up as you go even closer to the edge. It feels so natural.

Here's how we want it to work and then how sortablejs currently works

**react-beautiful-dnd**

[image: react-beautiful-dnd-scroll]

**sortablejs**

[image: sortablejs-scroll]

I moved from react-beautiful-dnd to sortablejs because it doesn't support a tree-like nested list. But the auto-scroll of sortablejs just isn't something we can deploy to users because it feels so buggy that it feels like it barely works and it makes the whole UX looks so bad. So I'm literally stuck like many users of sortablejs who submitted issues regarding the auto-scroll.

### If you know how to achieve this or know a different library that has both good scroll and nested/tree-like structure support please do suggest.

here's a clean and simple codesandbox to test the scroll

https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-sortablejs-scroll-test-fmch4

Comment: Because its a third party library the only thing you could do is go into the libraries code yourself and make changes. There is nothing on stack-overflow to solve the issue if you implemented it as described in the libraries documentation. You will either have to find another library, wait for the maintainers to fix it, or edit the libraries code directly from your node modules.

Comment: Muuri provides a much smoother autoscroll experience out of the box than Sortablejs. Take a look at this Kanban scrolling containers demo: https://codepen.io/niklasramo/pen/BrYaOp

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `forceFallback: true` in the config. After that, the `scrollSensitivity` will start working.